# error code EINTEGRITY with WARN tarball seems to be corrrupted... on npm install

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, npm, node-modules

I am using windows 10
recently from the last 3 day i am encountering an issue while installing the dependencies in my react+vite project,

when ever i try to download the dependencies using `npm install` i get an error as

```
npm WARN tarball tarball data for fast-levenshtein@https://registry.npmjs.org/fast-levenshtein/-/fast-levenshtein-2.0.6.tgz (sha512-DCXu6Ifhqcks7TZKY3Hxp3y6qphY5SJZmrWMDrKcERSOXWQdMhU9Ig/PYrzyw/ul9jOIyh0N4M0tbC5hodg8dw==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha512-DCXu6Ifhqcks7TZKY3Hxp3y6qphY5SJZmrWMDrKcERSOXWQdMhU9Ig/PYrzyw/ul9jOIyh0N4M0tbC5hodg8dw== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-DCXu6Ifhqcks7TZKY3Hxp3y6qphY5SJZmrWMDrKcERSOXWQdMhU9Ig/PYrzyw/ul9jOIyh0N4M0tbC5hodg8dw== but got sha512-DCXu6Ifhqcks7TZKYnHxp3y6qphY5SJZmrWMDrKcERSOXWQdMhU9Ig/PYrzyw/ul9jOIyh0N4M0tbC5hodg8dw==. (3699 bytes)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\AlanT\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-02-03T14_33_15_371Z-debug-0.log
```

Here are the solutions i tried but none worked:

1. Deleting the node modules and package-lock.json and then executing `npm cache verify` or `npm cache clean --force` and then re installing using `npm install` (tried it several times but this does not work).
2. I tried uninstalling node.js and reinstalling it

Nothing worked out please help.

Answer (score 0):

The `EINTEGRITY` error suggests that the SHA-512 checksum of the package data does not match the expected value, which is a security measure to ensure that the package has not been tampered with.

Ensure that your `.npmrc` file is pointing to the correct registry or you have the latest stable version of `npm` by running `npm install -g npm@latest.`

Then try deleting the `node modules` and `package-lock.json` and then run `npm cache clean --force` and then re-installing the modules using `npm install`